# file decoded with ffmpeg has different CRC to file decoded with flac.exe

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

Decoding the same .flac file (24-bit/48khz, 5.1 audio) with flac.exe, and then decoding the same .flac with ffmpeg results in two .wav files that have different CRC-32 values.

Command for decoding with flac.exe:
`flac -d input.flac`

Command for decoding with ffmpeg:
`ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a pcm_s24le output.wav`

Both of the resulting flac files are 24-bit signed little endian PCM files, at 48khz. Both are the exact same size on disk, but they do not have the same CRC-32 values. What am I doing wrong?

> OS: Windows 10 1909
>
> flac version: 1.3.2
>
> ffmpeg build: ffmpeg-20200312-675bb1f-win64-static

Comment: ffmpeg will write some metadata tags like Writing Application. flac may too. You should be comparing raw streams (not in containers like wav). Set all the encoding parameters and use the streamhash muxer in ffmpeg. Do the equivalent with flac.